# Windows 7: Scheduler with xcopy don't copy new files

Tags: windows, windows-7, task, scheduled-tasks

I've created a batch file to copy files from my machine to a backup machine. The batch file is this:

```
@echo off
cd D:\Backup
echo %date% %time% - Starting backup process. >> D:\Backup\backup_log.txt
xcopy D:\T\Source I:\AREA\USER\Backup\T\Source /s/d/y/c/v/r/i/e >> D:\Backup\backup_log.txt
echo %date% %time% - Stopping backup process. >> D:\Backup\backup_log.txt
exit
```

When running this bat file as command line, it copies all the new files and folders from source folder to a destination folder. Makes an update of the Source folder in I:\AREA\USER\Backup\T\Source. This is what I want.

```
D:\Backup>Backup.bat
```

But when I configure the same bat execution using Windows Task Scheduler, the scheduler runs without any errors but doesn't copy/update the new files.

I'm using Windows 7. I've made some tests and with this scenario, I can't see where the problem is. Maybe some configuration on Task Scheduler. I've read the information of the `xcopy` parameters. But with these parameters work in command line, why it doesn't work using windows scheduler?

Any help?
Thanks!
Filipe

**Edit1:** I've found something that can help to parse the error. If, in the Task Scheduler, I select the option *Run only when user is logged on*, it works. But when I select the other option *Run whether user is logged on or not*, it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't use drive letters in any program that runs with a different user account.  Like task scheduler.  Use the UNC name, `\\machinename\sharename\etcetera`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... I resolve my problem with this.
The bat file is:

```
@echo off
cd D:\Backup
echo %date% %time% - Starting backup process. >> D:\Backup\backup_log.txt
xcopy "D:\T\Source" "I:\AREA\USER\Backup\T\Source" /D /E /C /R /H /I /K /Y /V >> D:\Backup\backup_log.txt
echo %date% %time% - Stopping backup process. >> D:\Backup\backup_log.txt
exit
```

In the Task Scheduler, I've changed the General tab and check *"Run only when user is logged on"*.

I don't know, but in my understanding, the *"Run whether user is logged on or not"* should work when the user is logged.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue running bat file with XCOPY via Task Scheduler with *"Run whether user is logged on or not"* set. The ussue was that I have a network location **\\domain** mapped as disc **D:** thus my cmd was like

```
XCOPY /d /y \\192.168.1.1\Data D:\Data
```

It was running fine just by executing bat file, but task runner didn't copy anything. I've changed it to

```
XCOPY /d /y \\192.168.1.1\Data \\domain\Data
```

And everything was fine since then.